# How best to perform a query on primary partition key only, for a table which has both partition key and sort key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

Ok, I have a table with primary partition key (Employee ID) and Sort Key (Poject ID). Now I want a list of all projects an employee works on. Also I want list of all employees working on a project. The relationship is many to many. I have created schema in AppSync (GraphQL). Appsync created the required queries and mutations for the type (EmployeeProjects). Now the ListEmployeeProjects takes a filter input with different attributes. My question is when I do the two searches on Employee ID or Project ID only, will it be a complete table scan? How efficient will that be. If it is a table scan, can I reduce the time complexity by creating indexes (GSI or LSI). The end product will have huge amount of data, so I cannot test the app with such data before hand. My project works fine, but I am worried about the problems that might arise later on with a lot of data. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to (and should not) perform a [Scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) for this.

To get all of the projects an employee is working on, you just need to perform a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on the base table, specifying employee ID as the partition key.

To get all of the employees on a project, you should create a GSI on the table. The partition key should be project ID and sort key should be employee ID. Then perform a Query on the GSI, using partition key of project ID.

In order to model this correctly you will probably want three tables

1. Employee Table
2. Project Table
3. Employee-Project reference table (i.e. just two attributes of employee ID and project ID)